# BlurBehind - Failed to find in Android Studio dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I'm trying use BlurBehind Lib but I getting a error.

```
Error:Failed to find: com.faradaj:blur-behind:[LATEST_RELEASE_VERSION]
```

I added

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.faradaj:blur-behind:[LATEST_RELEASE_VERSION]'
}
```

I'm still adapting to the new IDE, and I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things here.

First of all, this library is not distributed from JCenter or even Maven Central. 
That means that you need to build it from source. Feel free to +1 [this issue](https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind/issues/2).
Luckily, it's rather straightforward, just follow the [github instructions](https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind).

Once you done that, you'll need to specify the version instead of `[LATEST_RELEASE_VERSION]`.
At the moment [it's 1.0.3](https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind/blob/master/blur-behind/build.gradle#L40).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had checked that the latest version on the github, but I had not found the other information you have provided, these here in the your  response.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you properly add this library:

**Step one**

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
}
```

**Step two**

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.github.faradaj:BlurBehind:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: ok sorry you are right that that's where it says to do this but it still cannot resolve.

Comment: Try adding the two classes (BlurBehind.java and util/Blur.java) in your project manually https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind/tree/master/blur-behind/src/main/java/com/faradaj/blurbehind

Comment: well that worked, thanks for the suggestion. Don't know why I didn't think of doing that, I've resorted to this as a final solution several times. Thanks again